# British citizen thinking of moving to Spain with Thai wife

Tags: eu-citizens, non-citizens

I am a British citizen of Spanish parents who is contemplating moving to Spain with my Thai wife  and daughter so we can be closer to my parents.

I am in the middle of getting my daughter her British passport, but I am unsure if we will be  able to live in Spain once the U.K. leaves the European Union.

What would we need to do to live legally in Spain?

Comment: With Spanish parents, do you have Spanish citizenship as well?

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to be Spanish, but if you are truly certain that you are not, the next simplest would be to move to Spain before Brexit.  Unfortunately, however, the details are still somewhat uncertain.

Comment: As a follow-on to gnasher's question, where were you born and how did you become a British citizen?